# Using Terraform to create GCE instances, error occuring on attaching secondary disk?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, terraform

My terraform file looks like this.

```
resource "google_compute_disk" "sqlserversecondary" {
    name = "sql-server-secondary"
    type = "pd-ssd"
    zone = "us-central1-a"
    size = "512"
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "sqlserver2016rc2" {
    name = "sqlserver2016rc2"
    machine_type = "n1-highmem-8"

    tags = ["database", "sqlserver2016rc2"]
    zone = "us-central1-a"

    disk {
        image = "sqlserver2016"
        size = "120"
    }

    disk {
        image = "sql-server-secondary"
    }

    network_interface {
        network = "default"
        access_config {
            // Ephemeral IP
        }
    }

    service_account {
        scopes = ["userinfo-email", "compute-ro", "storage-ro"]
    }
}
```

The second disk exists in GCE, but in this particular situation I keep getting the following error.

```
Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* google_compute_instance.sqlserver2016rc2: Error creating instance: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.disks[1].initializeParams': ''. Cannot specify initializeParams for non-boot persistent disks., invalid
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your second disk, you want to use `disk = "sql-server-secondary"` instead of `image` as the identifier. Also, it's best to reference the second disk using Terraform's interpolation syntax (e.g. `${...}`) to ensure your resources are created and managed in the appropriate order.

```
resource "google_compute_disk" "sqlserversecondary" {
  name = "sql-server-secondary"
  type = "pd-ssd"
  zone = "us-central1-a"
  size = "512"
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "sqlserver2016rc2" {
  name         = "sqlserver2016rc2"
  machine_type = "n1-highmem-8"

  tags = ["database", "sqlserver2016rc2"]
  zone = "us-central1-a"

  disk {
    image = "ubuntu-1404-trusty-v20160114e"
    size  = "120"
  }

  disk {
    disk = "${google_compute_disk.sqlserversecondary.name}" // s/image/disk
  }

  network_interface {
    network = "default"

    access_config {
      // Ephemeral IP
    }
  }

  service_account {
    scopes = ["userinfo-email", "compute-ro", "storage-ro"]
  }
}
```

Terraform sets `InitializeParams` for disks that are from pre-existing images ([code](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/c280d621892be81b99724e3cf86eb6a6e1a84731/builtin/providers/google/resource_compute_instance.go#L383-L395)) which is causing the error you received. It seems there may be a bug in this scenario, attaching a non-boot disk from an existing image, but I'm still digging into that.

Hope this helps!